# javascript - how to return Json conditionally

Tags: javascript, json

Is it possible to change from below

```
  if(true){
    return {
      ...baseData,
      email: profile.email,
      permissions: "admin",
    };
  }else{
    return {
      ...baseData,
      email: profile.email,
    };
  }
```

to something like

```
    return {
      ...baseData,
      email: profile.email,
      permissions: <some code>,
    };
```

?